# Error in My Queue datastructres implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I'm trying to implement a Queue using a linked list, but I get this error when I pass an integer to the `enqueue` function in `main`

> Exception thrown: write access violation.
>
> this->tail was nullptr.

here is my Queue.h

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T >
class Node
{
public:
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node();
    Node(T _data);
};

template <class T>
class Queue
{

public:
    Node<T> *head, *tail;
    int elemsCnt;
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    int count();
    void clear();
    void enqueue(T);
    T dequeue();
    T front();
    T back();
    bool empty();
};
```

and this is my Queue.cpp which i wrote the functions ..
    #include "Queue.h"

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    next = NULL;
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T _data)
{
    data = _data;
    next = NULL;
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
{
    head = tail = NULL;
    elemsCnt = 0;
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue()
{
    clear();
}

template <class T>
int Queue<T>::count()
{
    return elemsCnt;
}

template <class T>
bool Queue<T>::empty()
{
    return(elemsCnt == 0);
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T val)
{
    Node<T>* inserted = new Node<T>(val);
    tail->next = inserted;
    tail = inserted;
    ++elemsCnt;
}

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::dequeue()
{
    Node<T>* deleted = head;
    T val = head->data;
    head = head->next;
    delete deleted;
    --elemsCnt;

    if (empty())
        tail = NULL;

    return val;
}

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::front()
{
    return head->data;
}

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::back()
{
    return tail->data;
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::clear()
{
    while (!empty())
    {
        Node<T>* deleted = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete deleted;
        --elemsCnt;
    }
    tail = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because initially your Queue is empty. when you have:

```
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T val)
{
    Node<T>* inserted = new Node<T>(val);
    tail->next = inserted; //at this point tail is still NULL
    //it is illegal to try to access * and . on NULL

    tail = inserted;
    ++elemsCnt;
}
```

if you want to fix it try this:

```
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T val)
{
    Node<T>* inserted = new Node<T>(val);

    if(this->elemsCnt==0)
    {
        //empty Queue
        this->head=inserted;
        this->tail=inserted;
    }
    else
    {
        //non empty
        inserted->next=this->head; //make sure the new head can point to older head
        this->head=inserted; update the pointer for head.

    }
    ++elemsCnt;
}
```

Comment: for a Queue you don't really need a tail so don't worry about it too much. If your queue is empty, tail is NULL, or else it is the last element. not useful for a Queue.

Answer (score 0):

just like the exception says, tail is NULL.  Your enqueue method is not handling the case when the list is empty (head == tail == null).

```
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T val)
{
    Node<T>* inserted = new Node<T>(val);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail = inserted;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = inserted;
        tail = inserted;
    }
    ++elemsCnt;
}
```

Comment: would have to see the sequence of enqueues/dequeues, since logic looks correct to me. I did just noticed that in dequeue and clear, you are not setting head to null as well as tail when the last item is removed. So, I could see this exception if you enqueue, dequeue, then enqueue again.